# Embed Codenameone Youtube Video

Tags: youtube, embed, codenameone

I've been trying to embed a youtube video within a codename one application. When I run the simulator for both Android and iOS it looks fine, but when I actually run the application on my Galaxy S7, nothing shows. I've tried using both BrowserComponent and WebBrowser and neither work. My code is below:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());                    
    Display display = Display.getInstance();

    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    //WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    String videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/r6VO3zaBJGY";

    int videoWidth = (int) ((double) display.getDisplayWidth());
    int videoHeight = (int) ((double) videoWidth*0.5625);     

    String integrationCode= "<iframe src=\"" +videoUrl+"\" frameborder=\"0\"  width=\"" + videoWidth + "\" height=\"" + videoHeight + "\" allow=\"autoplay; encrypted-media\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    browser.setPage(integrationCode, null);
    browser.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    browser.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);

    Container browserContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout(CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
    browserContainer.add(CENTER, browser);          
    hi.add(browserContainer);

    hi.show();
```

Comment: Hello I get "Refused to display the link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.", source: https://cn1app/streams/1 (0) , please how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the code: `BoxLayout` and `CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER`.

The reason this won't work has to do with the way layouts work. Layout managers use the preferred size to give components the right size. `BrowserComponent` doesn't have a proper preferred size as the rendering of HTML is asynchronous and it's pretty flexible to begin with. In this case you used two layout managers that respect preferred size. They get a size that amounts to zero and place the browser component appropriately...

`BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` needs the preferred height and `CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER` needs the preferred size to position the component in the center.

The typical workaround is to use a regular `BorderLayout` which defaults to the scaled behavior. This stretches the center component to take up available space. Notice you need to set it on the `Form` itself as it has a hardcoded size of the entire screen. The center location ignores the preferred size and gives the component the full size.

It also solves another problem. `Form` is scrollable by default on the Y axis. Scrollability for Codename One components and native widgets (e.g. web) can collide so by using the border layout you implicitly disable scrolling which in this case might provide superior UX.

Note that you can get the code above to work by overriding `calcPreferredSize()` in `BrowserComponent` and returning the size you want for the component. I don't think this will result in a good UX because of scrollability issues.

Comment: Hello I get "Refused to display the link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.", source: https://cn1app/streams/1 (0) , please how to fix this

Comment: I think you need to update the embed code to use the new youtube embed code. You can get that from the video you wish to embed.

Comment: Hey Shai It's done. I have another question so I'm going to post it right now on Google Discussions!